# MYSQL slow large amount of data insert

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, local

I have made a process to insert information in database of MYSQL Server, I need insert information from an XML Files, those XML Files has a lot of information, the size of them are (500mb aprox). So I extract only the information that I want and I save it in a text file separated by pipes.

I made in this way to process the information faster with the LOCAL DATA INFILE statement of MYSQL Server to insert the information in a exactly copy of the main table with (52 columns aprox), I made an exactly copy of it to insert the information, and after it execute an stored procedure to insert the information of the copy table to the original and put some conditions to avoid the duplicate the data.

So I have the INSERT STATEMENT in the stored procedure like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table 
(
  Col1,
  Col2,
  Col3,
  COl4,
  Etc..
)
SELECT 
DISTINCT
Col1,
Col2,
COl3,
Col4,
Etc..
FROM TableTemp tmp WHERE tmp.File = 1 tmp.Action = 'A' 
AND NOT EXISTS ( 
SELECT * FROM Table PC 
WHERE PC.Col1 = tmp.Col1 
AND COALESCE(PC.Col2,0) = COALESCE(tmp.Col2,0)
AND COALESCE(PC.Col3,0) = COALESCE(tmp.Col3,0)  
AND COALESCE(PC.Col4,0) = COALESCE(tmp.Col4,0) 
AND ETC...
```

Note: I have COALESCE between the NOT EXISTS clause because I want to avoid the null values duplicated, and MySQL doesn't work if I use NULL = NULL.

Whatever, to make an idea, the TableTemp has 200k of rows, and the main table (Table) has aprox 9million of rows.

So when I execute the stored procedure to insert the information into the main table, it took a lot of time to make this operation, (there are times when it takes up to three hours).

The main table has some index column (in 5 columns I have index, and also a Unique Key in multiples columns, in 5 columns)

I would like listen for better ways to do it, or if I'm doing something wrong, because takes a lot of time to insert the information in the main table without duplicate values.

I hope some of you can help me,

Thank u.

Comment: "MySQL doesn't work if I use NULL = NULL" - See: [NULL-safe equal to operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to).

Comment: Yes, I already check that, thats why I'm using coalesce to compare nulls (set value to 0 if the column is empty), so with this I pretend to avoid null values in columns. But the main point its reduce the time of the insert statement.

Comment: "Yes, I already check that" - I doubt that. Please read the docs again.